# Moving an element with invisible content

Tags: jquery, html, dom, dom-manipulation

I have a page that loads with content. I `.clone()` certain elements, then hide the originals, then I append the cloned elements to the dom. There is one element in particular that is connected to a CMS field where a user can add scripts and content. The field will show even if there is nothing inside it.

[image: div with children that are not visible]

This box can consist of a myriad of html nodes, mainly five groups.

1. comments `<!-- -->`
2. script tags `<script></scripts>`
3. images used for analytics tracking containing `zferral` usualy `display:none`
4. text `plain text` (not wrapped in html)
5. html `<b>hello</b>`

I want to show this box if it has plain text or html (that is not `display:none`).

To reiterate, I move this box so I wan't a `bool` that says if I should put it in with javascript or not.

Comment: so you want a function that can run on a div to determine if it contains any visible things?

Comment: also... why? Why would you need to do this? Why not just cause the content to output in the proper location from the serverside? Or use `appendTo` to move the element without cloneing?

Comment: Don't have access to the serverside, it is a app that works with another platform. I need to move it get the contents and delegate to put it back or not.

Comment: I can use `appendTo` but its still going to append a empty div box and I dont want that.

Comment: Ok so then are you really just looking for a function to test if a div contains visalbe elements or not?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could place a wrapper div (with 0 padding, 0 margins, no border, overflow hidden, auto width, auto height) inside your box where you put everything in. Then simply use jquery to calculate the dimensions of that box. If its dimensions are zero. it contains no visible elements. The only case in which this won't work is if the contents are html elements having  position absolute/fixed.